# VirtualBox: How can I run an application in my host environment

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

For instance, I have a virtualised Linux-box running in my windows environment, and I have a shared-folder mapped to `/vagrant` and in that shared folder I have `readme.txt`. Is there a command I can run from within the virtualised OS to pop up `readme.txt` in my favourite text-editor in the windows host environment?

In a nutshell I'm just wondering if there is a standard way to invoke a host command from the guest.

I'm thinking an analogue of the `cygstart` command that cygwin provides, perhaps a part of the guest additions package.

This seems like it should be a well trodden path, since its highly likely a guest might want to communicate with its host in certain configurations.

Comment: I really don't understand your problem, you just need to open the file with the text editor you wish

Comment: It's more generalised than that. I want to issue a command from my guest environment that runs in the host. The text-editor is an example.

Comment: The guest and the host are individual machines. They can communicate via known RPC protocols - as if they where both physical machines.

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks, that's a mechanism by which this problem could be solved (I'm thinking an alternative might be by way of VB's host integration tools & APIs). I'm expecting this is a problem that has been solved before, so I am seeking an "established" approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like somebody wrote a tool for this https://github.com/marcosdiez/openfile

Unfortunately it looks like there isn't a VirtualBox API for this so he has to run a server in the host:

> it is necessary to run a C# server on Windows which accepts and runs
>   remote commands from the Unix box.

Should do the job though!